# How can i add multiple address in django?

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, backend

I am trying to add multiple addresses but only 1 address is getting created

**This is models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
locality = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
city = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
zipcode = models.IntegerField()
state = models.CharField(choices = STATE_CHOICES, max_length=50)
```

**This is views.py**

```
def address(request):
add = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
return render(request, 'app/address.html', {'add':add})
```

**This is address.py**

```
{% for ad in add %}
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
   <h3>Address {{forloop.counter}}</h3>
   <p>Name: {{ad.name}}</p>
   <p>Locality: {{ad.locality}}</p>
   <p>City: {{ad.city}}</p>
   <p>Pin Code: {{ad.zipcode}}</p>
   <p>State: {{ad.state}}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**this is admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['id', 'name', 'user', 'locality', 'city',
'zipcode', 'state'] 

@admin.register(Address)
class AddressModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['id', 'user', 'name', 'locality',
'city', 'state', 'zipcode']
```

---

Comment: Where is your view to add multiple addresses ?

Comment: bro i am following a tutorial there is no such code for multiple addresses still i works for him. Should i share link of that tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean that an user can have many addresses ? the model is showing an address per user
you should add new Model Address to be able to proceed in this case. here an example:
`models.py` file

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="customer"
    )
    locality = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField(choices = STATE_CHOICES, max_length=50)
```

in `views.py`

```py
def addresses(request):
    addresses = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'app/address.html', {'addresses':addresses})
```

in `address.html`

```html
{% if addresses %}
    {% for ad in addresses %}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>Address {{forloop.counter}}</h3>
                    <p>Name: {{ad.user.name}}</p>
                    <p>Locality: {{ad.locality}}</p>
                    <p>City: {{ad.city}}</p>
                    <p>Pin Code: {{ad.zipcode}}</p>
                    <p>State: {{ad.state}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

file `admin.py`

```py
@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Customer
    list_display = ['id', 'name'] 

@admin.register(Address)
class AddressModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Address
    list_display = ['id', 'user', 'locality', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode']
```

NB: you should render the available fields in the model in list_display

this code is not tested, please test it first

Comment: this is throwing this error: ValueError at /address/

Cannot query "admin": Must be "Customer" instance.     I have added admin.py in this question so take a look at it also

Comment: I updated my answer, please read the documentation about list_display https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display
your best tutorial is documentation

Comment: @PiyushDive does this reply to your question? if so please accept the answer, thank you

Comment: it's still showing this error: ValueError at /address/ Cannot query "admin": Must be "Customer" instance.

Comment: did you specify the model in your modeladmin? and why you did not report your error till now? and the question in beginning was not about modeladmin but about your view ... did my answer fixed your view error?

Comment: I added the model, please print all the error log so I can understand it

Comment: yes! it gives this error: ValueError at /address/ Cannot query "admin": Must be "Customer" instance. "admin" here is the username of user. and highlightes this line from views.py: addresses = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user).

Comment: did you run migrations? after adding new model Address ? adrresses should return empty queryset if the user is not having any address, after adding new model, you should run migration: `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` and your previous comments was not clear, I thought that you are talking about `admin.py` and not user that you called admin

Comment: and your admin account is not a customer, you need to add a condition if your user is a customer or no

Comment: how can i do that...i mean, i want to allow user to create multiple addresses. a user can have multiple addresses. i just can't figure it out how to do that !